# jquery animate complete

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, jquery-animate

```js
<div class="factuuradres"></br><h3></h3></div>
<div class="factuuradresbutton">Meer Informatie</div>           

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".factuuradresbutton").toggle(function(){
        $(".factuuradres").animate({
            height: "310px"
        }, 500 );
        complete: function() {
            $(".factuuradresbutton").html("Toch geen factuuradres")
            $(".factuuradres").html('<h2>Factuuradres</h2><div class="title_textbox3"><h3>Postcode:</h3></div><div class="textbox3"><input type="text" class="postcode" name="Postcode" value=""/></div><div class="title_textbox4"><h3>Huisnummer:</h3></div><div class="textbox4"><input type="text" class="huisnummer" name="Huisnummer" value=""/></div><div class="title_textbox"><h3>Straat:</h3></div><div class="textbox"><input type="text" class="field" name="Straat" value=""/></div><div class="title_textbox"><h3>Plaats:</h3></div><div class="textbox"><input type="text" class="field" name="Plaats" value=""/></div>')
        }
    },

    function(){
        $(".factuuradres").animate({
            height: "160px"
        }, 500 );
        $(".factuuradresbutton").html("Ander factuuradres?")
        $(".factuuradres").html("Factuuradres")
    });
</script>
```

I'm wondering why the `complete: function()` is not working, anyone who can give me advice?

Also this is the working script, but it breaks once you click on the button. After an second or two it works like intended.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".factuuradresbutton").toggle(function(){
    $(".factuuradres").animate({
        height: "610px"
    }, 500 );
    $(".factuuradresbutton").html("Toch geen factuuradres")
    $(".factuuradres").html('<h2>Factuuradres</h2><div class="title_textbox3"><h3>Postcode:</h3></div><div class="textbox3"><input type="text" class="postcode" name="Postcode" value=""/></div><div class="title_textbox4"><h3>Huisnummer:</h3></div><div class="textbox4"><input type="text" class="huisnummer" name="Huisnummer" value=""/></div><div class="title_textbox"><h3>Straat:</h3></div><div class="textbox"><input type="text" class="field" name="Straat" value=""/></div><div class="title_textbox"><h3>Plaats:</h3></div><div class="textbox"><input type="text" class="field" name="Plaats" value=""/></div>')
    },
    function(){
    $(".factuuradres").animate({
        height: "160px"
    }, 500 );
    $(".factuuradresbutton").html("Ander factuuradres?")
    $(".factuuradres").html("Factuuradres")
    });
</script>
```

Comment: where are you invoking the complete function ? your animate call gets closed with ); after the 500

Comment: Check the console. Your answer will be the syntax error in there.

Comment: Your syntax is incorrect. Run your code through [JSHint](http://jshint.com).

Comment: try to make success function as callback function of animate.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/t3ttW/ currently using(and working) script.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Just seen your comment and changed my answer to this: http://jsfiddle.net/t3ttW/1/

```
$(".factuuradresbutton").toggle(function () {
      $(".factuuradres").animate({
        height: "610px"
      }, {
        duration: 500,
        complete: function () {
          $(".factuuradresbutton").html("Toch geen factuuradres")
          $(".factuuradres").html('<h2>Factuuradres</h2><div class="title_textbox3"><h3>Postcode:</h3></div><div class="textbox3"><input type="text" class="postcode" name="Postcode" value=""/></div><div class="title_textbox4"><h3>Huisnummer:</h3></div><div class="textbox4"><input type="text" class="huisnummer" name="Huisnummer" value=""/></div><div class="title_textbox"><h3>Straat:</h3></div><div class="textbox"><input type="text" class="field" name="Straat" value=""/></div><div class="title_textbox"><h3>Plaats:</h3></div><div class="textbox"><input type="text" class="field" name="Plaats" value=""/></div>');
        }
      });
    },

    function () {
      $(".factuuradres").animate({
        height: "160px"
      }, 500);
      $(".factuuradresbutton").html("Ander factuuradres?")
      $(".factuuradres").html("Factuuradres")
    });
```

Comment: Im using toggle, so if i click on the button, the text what's inside the "factuuradres" div is going visible, but with this script the button isnt working anymore.
(check main post, updated an working script, but I would like to have the complete function.

Answer (score 8):

```
    $(".factuuradres").animate({
        height: "310px"
    }, 500, function() {
        $(".factuuradresbutton").html("Toch geen factuuradres")
        $(".factuuradres").html('<h2>Factuuradres</h2><div class="title_textbox3"><h3>Postcode:</h3></div><div class="textbox3"><input type="text" class="postcode" name="Postcode" value=""/></div><div class="title_textbox4"><h3>Huisnummer:</h3></div><div class="textbox4"><input type="text" class="huisnummer" name="Huisnummer" value=""/></div><div class="title_textbox"><h3>Straat:</h3></div><div class="textbox"><input type="text" class="field" name="Straat" value=""/></div><div class="title_textbox"><h3>Plaats:</h3></div><div class="textbox"><input type="text" class="field" name="Plaats" value=""/></div>')
    });
```

Comment: The way 'animate' is having its callback its wrong. @Jay answer is correct.

Answer (score 3):

The callback function to be called when an animation completes is a parameter to the animate function.  Currently the code is not passing the function as a parameter.

Comment: @RinkeDoeser I like James Donnelly's solution, its demonstrating what my verbiage suggests.